# Why the output of regression task DNN is normal-like distributed?

Tags: deep-learning, regression, recurrent-neural-network

I'm training DNN network to fit a regression task, and the target `Y` is uniformal distributed. But through the tensorboard I see the output of the network is normal-like distributed.
So how to deal with this ? Or is it necessary to assert the target to be normal-distributed?

Answer (score 0):

How does your final layer look like? That might help to understand what's going on.

However, even with the best architecture you will run into the following problem:

Let's assume your uniform distribution is 0 to 1. There most likely are training samples that have the same or very similar input, but vastly different outputs. Let's say in one of those cases we have the same inputs and the outputs are 0.2 and 0.8. The best guess to these inputs is 0.5.

You can construct more examples like this, however the closer we get to the edge, the more difficult or even impossible it becomes to create those. For the example to create a 0.95 best fit, you could even argue that 0.91 and 0.99 are so close that 0.95 is a good prediction for both.

So this bell like curve you see is a very natural outcome.

If your data does not include such points, another reason - but with the same result - would appear if your model was not able to learn all the patterns. If it had to completely guess an output, the one with the lowest error is directly in the middle. And with little more information you can go slightly left or right.

So, what can you do? You could try to force a more uniform distribution. Ideas:

- Add weights to the training samples. The closer to the edge, the higher.
- Oversample your points on the edges.
- Add the difference to a uniform distribution to the loss function. Might be tricky to set up. But if you manage to do that, this would be the most natural and repeatable way to solve it.